# Worksheet Order - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set an order for worksheets in excel using PowerShell.
I thought it would have been fairly straight forward using the code below but it does not seem to be moving.

I have a workbook, which has a sheet called 'RISKSUMMARY', i am trying to move this to be the first sheet in the file. Position number 1, then will move another sheet to be position number 2 etc.

```ps
$sheet1 = $Workbook.Worksheets["RISKSUMMARY"]
$sheet1 = $Workbook.Worksheets(1)

$sheet1 = $Workbook.Worksheets["RISKSUMMARY"]
$sheet1 = $Workbook.Worksheets(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will get your specified worksheet name and move it to your specified sheet position, '1' for the first sheet. You can also change the `movePosition` variable so it can be inserted in other positions.

```
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$mypath = "C:\Some Path\mysheet.xlsx"
$workSheetName = "RISKSUMMARY"
$workBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($mypath)
$movePosition = 1

# get all wowrksheets
$worksheets = $workBook.WorkSheets

# iterate through all worksheets
foreach ($worksheet in $worksheets){

    # stop at sheet with specified name and move it to specified position
    if ($worksheet.Name -eq $workSheetName){
        # move sheet to the front
        if ($movePosition -eq 1){
            $worksheet.move($worksheets[1])
        }
        # if position is at end of list
        elseif ($movePosition -eq $worksheets.Count){                
            $prevWorkSheet = $worksheets[$movePosition]           
            $worksheet.move($worksheets[$movePosition])         
            $prevWorkSheet.move($worksheet)
        }
        # if anywhere else
        else{                   
            $prevWorkSheet = $worksheets[$movePosition]           
            $worksheet.move($worksheets[$movePosition])     
        }
        
        break
    }

}
$workBook.save()
$workBook.close()
```